# questions about importing in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, import

i've seen plenty of importing questions but didn't find any that explained importing very "easily". there are are 3 types of importing that i know of, and none of them seem to do what i'm looking for or would like to do. eg. main.py has def a()   def b()  class c() and def d()  and lets say i have a start.py file.

main:

```
def a():
    print("1")

def b():
    print("2")

class c():
    def__init__(self,name = "Rick")
        self.name = name

def d():
    print("4")
```

so now im my start.py file   i want to import everything from them. what is the best way?  i have tried using    import main    and i run into issues after creating an instance of class c  [ ricky = c()  ]that ricky isn't defined or accessing ricky.name it will say module ricky has no attribute name. so that doesn't seem to work.  what is this even used for if you aren't importing the entire main.py file?

then there is from main import a, b, c, d  that seems to work just fine, but there really has to be another way than having to import every single function, definition, variable, and everything.

third there is  from main import *  i'm not sure how this one works, i have read some on it mainly stating there should be an __ *all* __ = everything i want imported. but where do i put this. at the very top of the page inside my main.py?  but there still should be a better way?

is my import main just not working correctly?  or do i have to list everything i want to import either in a from main import statement or in an __ *all* __ list?

does importing carry over to another py file?   eg. 1.py 2.py 3.py   if inside 2.py i import 3.py correctly and everything works.  in 1.py  can i just import 2.py  and it will import 3.py into 1.py from the import statement inside of 2.py?  or do i have to import 2.py and 3.py again into 1.py?

Comment: Those are invalid names for functions and classes, (starting with) a digit. Please adjust your example to be actual valid code.

Comment: If you define the special `__all__` variable, to a list of functions, classes, variables etc in the current module, then *only* those functions/classes/variables/etc will be imported during `from main import *`. Otherwise, everything will just be imported. So `__all__` restricts global imports.

Comment: As for the question in your last paragraph: have you actually *tried* that? That's the best way to find out and answer your question.

Comment: so using:   

    from main import * will import everything from the main.py file. adding the __all__ and listing what i want to be imported will work, only reason to do that is if i don't want everything imported. meaning it would be identical to using:   from main import a, b ,c ,d ....z.  
what is the use of  import main   then? 
and no i haven't tried looping the imports together. something i thought of while i was asking this question.

Comment: The reasoning in the first part of your comment is correct.

Comment: I don't fully understand yoru question "what is the use of import main then?". But consider another module `blah`, that also has `a`, `b` and so on. Using `import main` and `import blah`, you can now distinguish between the different `a`'s, `b`'s etc: `main.a` vs `blah.a`. In fact, this is generally encouraged in Python. `from xyz import abc` is usually for a one-off case, with distinctive `abc` names.

Comment: import main.  what does it import.  because i have tried using it and i will get errors saying.  name ' x ' not defined. whenever calling a class, function, variable  in the main.py  it gave me problems .  

does from main import *  make everything global?   because i do have local variables that are the same. so i don't want that.

Comment: Yes, `form main import *` puts everything (depending on `__all__`) into the current module. If that module defines variables/functions/classes with the same name, things get overwritten.

Comment: If you use `import main` in your script, you definitely should be able to use `main.x` and so on afterwards. If you get an error, you should provide a [MCVE] showcasing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 3 main imports:

import (pythonfile) aka "module"  using this will import all classes and functions to be used. does not import other imports.  to call something in the imported module eg. modlue: MAIN,  function: FUNC ...  to call: MAIN.FUNC()

from module import FUNC, CLASS, ....   when using this import you don't need to call it with the module. it is almost as if it is right infront of you  eg.
module: MAIN, function: FUNC .....  to call: FUNC()

from module import *  a combination of the previous two imports. will import everything from the module to be accessed without calling with the module extention. this form imports other imports as well. so if you have two modules that need to talk to eachother. using this will cause an error since you will be trying to import a module into another module then back into it's self again.  A imported into B,  A and B imported back into A. it doesn't work. so watch when using. May cause other importing errors of trying to import multiple modules that share imports. eg. importing A and B into C if A and B share D (pending for testing)
from MAIN import *  call function:  FUNC()

hope this helps other people out who are having issues understanding exactly how importing works and calling your functions/classes and what not.